# PHP Get Parent Info from MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I Have Two Tables, One of them Jobs and the Other Customers. Both Tables have Customer_ID, The Customer Table it is the primary and the Job has just a normal int field named Customer_ID. I Don't Want to use Foreign key because it doesn't display a value automatically. How can I get when the Row in the Job Table Has a Customer_ID # in the Customer Table have it Display the Customer_Name Field in the Customer Database?

```
// Data List from Table
$jobs_a = array();
$jobs_sql = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `MyDB`.`Jobs`")
while($jobs = $jobs_sql->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $customer_id = $jobs['Customer_ID'];
        $jobs_a[$customer_id] = $jobs;
}
```

Comment: So are you looking at a query to select the customer name along with the job details if there is a customer id ?

Answer (score 2):

In your `$conn->query` ,use a join on the two tables where jobsTable.custID = CustomerTable.custID.  Here is some join syntax documentation:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Here's a tutorial on it:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Answer (score 2):

Use MySQL JOINs

```
$jobs_sql = $conn->query("SELECT C.customer_name FROM `MyDB`.`Jobs` J 
  INNER JOIN `MyDB`.`Customers` C ON C.Customer_ID = J.Customer_ID
  WHERE J.Customer_ID IS NOT NULL
")
```